# ORACLE 11g case insensitive by default

Tags: oracle, configuration, oracle11g, case-insensitive

I found in [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/04-jul/o44asktom.html), that since ORACLE 10g, there is a way to make a particular connection-session compare strings case-insensitive, without needing any crazy SQL functions, using an `ALTER SESSION`.

Does anyone know if, in 11g, there might be a way to make the database to always operate in this mode by default for all new connection-sessions, thereby eliminating the need for running `ALTER SESSION`s every time you connect?

Or perhaps, an additional parameter you could specify on your connection string that would turn the same on?

Answer (score 7):

You could just set the `NLS_SORT`, `NLS_COMP` parameters mentioned in the article as the values in the the Oracle init file using the `alter system set <parameter> = <value>;` clause.

Info on using the alter system commands can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2013.htm#i2061284).

Here is a good [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm) on the correct usage of the `NLS_*` parameters.  Note that some settings of of the NLS_SORT parameter can/could cause performance issues, namely when it is not set to BINARY.  The Oracle docs state:

> Setting NLS_SORT to anything other
>   than BINARY causes a sort to use a
>   full table scan, regardless of the
>   path chosen by the optimizer. BINARY
>   is the exception because indexes are
>   built according to a binary order of
>   keys. Thus the optimizer can use an
>   index to satisfy the ORDER BY clause
>   when NLS_SORT is set to BINARY. If
>   NLS_SORT is set to any linguistic
>   sort, the optimizer must include a
>   full table scan and a full sort in the
>   execution plan.

Comment: While that quote is from the oracle documentation, it also makes no sense "regardless of the path chosen by the optimizer". A more useful reference for this is
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#sthref650

Comment: The "good link on the correct usage of the NLS_* parameters" I provided in my answer is the same link and information you provided except that the link in my answer is from the 11g documentation.

Comment: I'm working now with this issue and I found that to avoid performance issues, a CI Index can be created for the column: create index index_name on table_name (NLSSORT (column_name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI') ); [reference](http://geekzspot.blogspot.com.es/2010/01/case-insensitive-oracle-database.html)

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can!

Get your friendly DBA to set these parameters:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC SCOPE=SPFILE; 

ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

This is taken from my short article on [How to make Oracle Case Insensitive](http://geekzspot.blogspot.com/2010/01/case-insensitive-oracle-database.html)

Comment: What about the quote-out in RC's answer. Will doing this utterly destroy the performance of the system, as that would seem to indicate?

Answer (score 3):

I tried using a `logon trigger` to issue these commands to get case-insensitive queries:

```
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI';
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC';
```

And while that did give me CI, it also gave me unbelievably bad performance issues. We have one table in particular that, without those settings, inserts take 2 milliseconds. With those settings in place, inserts took 3 **seconds**. I have confirmed this by creating and dropping the trigger multiple times.

I don't know if doing it at the system level, as opposed to the session level with a trigger, makes a difference or not.

Comment: Eeks! That is quite the horrible performance hit! I can't believe ORACLE hasn't added better support for this yet. I mean, if you're searching invoices or comments or notes or pretty much any common text field you really don't care if someone writes "took the cat to the vet" or "Took the cat to the Vet".

Comment: After meeting with an Oracle consultant yesterday, we discovered that the trick to using these two settings is that you MUST put functional indexes in lots of places. In our case, we use varchar2(32) UUIDs for primary keys. Because of the two NSL settings, none of the normal PK indexes were being used. We had to add indexes like

create index foo_ok on Person(nlssort(Id, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'));

to all our PKs.

Comment: Egads! That's a lot of work just to treat "The Twilight Zone" as the same thing as "the twilight zone".

Comment: guess ORACLE'S still practically stuck in the world of storing everything in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same performance issue with inserts and nls in 11g r2! Luckily for me the performance hit was not significant enough requiring an app change.

If you can do without binary_ci for the INSERT, then I would do an alter session just before the insert and afterwards, so you don't have to drop the trigger