# How do i set case sensitivity 'off' for a Datasource in spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

So i have a spring based application which talks to an oracle 12c database and i want to turn off case sensitivity for the jdbctemplate.

I know this can be done by executing the following statements before i call the actual query. But i dont want to call these statements each and every time i make a database query. Is there something i can configure before my application starts?

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;  
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
```

Comment: "Turn off case insensitivity" = turn on case sensitivity? Isn't Oracle case sensitive in string comparisons by default?

Comment: Are you only using Oracle, or other RDBMS as well?

Comment: Only oracle is my datasource

Comment: If you have control over the DB, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001165/oracle-11g-case-insensitive-by-default) are some things you could try.

Comment: But apparently, I cannot modify the database, i have read only access.

Answer (score 0):

The [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) itself does not provide any sort of init scripts. But some [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementations might provide said feature.
For example the `Tomcat JDBC DataSource` has a [`setInitSQL(String sql)`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.html#setInitSQL(java.lang.String))-method. The given query is run when a connection is first created.

**Spring Boot** provides a [common `application.properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) config option for configuring the tomcat jdbc datasource:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initSQL=ALTER SESSION SET...
```